# Localhost no longer connects after installing VPN

Tags: reactjs, localhost, vpn

Ever since I installed Surkshark VPN my localhost has failed to connect to let me preview React apps on my browser. This occurs even when I disable or delete Surfshark. My localhost used to be `http://localhost:3000/` but now it's `http://localhost:5173/` provided by Vite and `http://127.0.0.1:5500/` when I use the Go Live extension on VSCode

I'm on a MacBook Pro running Mac OS 13.4.1 (22F82). I'm using Vite to create React apps, and when I first start it I'm about to view my React App on a localhost and make changes to the App.jsx. But once I restart a few times or create a new component, I get the following error:

```
This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

When I click go live from VSCode "Live Sever" extension I get a black page and I see console.log errors saying:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/jsx". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
:5500/vite.svg:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I see the following error messages in the Terminal in VSCode:

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@swc/wasm"

    ../node_modules/@swc/core/index.js:70:35:
      70 │         fallbackBindings = require('@swc/wasm');
         ╵                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "@swc/wasm" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove
  this error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this
  failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.

✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".node" files: ../node_modules/@swc/core-darwin-arm64/swc.darwin-arm64.node

    ../node_modules/@swc/core/binding.js:130:48:
      130 │                         nativeBinding = require('@swc/core-darwin-arm64');
          ╵                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

8:39:47 AM [vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 2 errors:
../node_modules/@swc/core/binding.js:130:48: ERROR: No loader is configured for ".node" files: ../node_modules/@swc/core-darwin-arm64/swc.darwin-arm64.node
../node_modules/@swc/core/index.js:70:35: ERROR: Could not resolve "@swc/wasm"
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/errolpierre-louis/eap-04/eap-05/eap-06/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1636:15)
    at /Users/errolpierre-louis/eap-04/eap-05/eap-06/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1048:25
    at /Users/errolpierre-louis/eap-04/eap-05/eap-06/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1512:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
8:40:00 AM [vite] hmr update /src/App.jsx
```

I'm very new to React and previewing on a localhost in general so I'm at a loss here. Installing my VPN broke something, but I can't figure out what. I have no firewall active btw.

I tried disabling and uninstalling my VPN, but I'm still having issues